# How to get loop value outside the loop with matrix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I wanna storage all For Loop value() with matrix，

but I don't know how to do it.

Thank you for your comments ~

```
import numpy as np

T1 = 3
T3 = 10

ydd = 0;
wdd = 0;
tt = 0;

t=0
for t in np.arange (t,T3,0.001) :  
    if t <= T1:
        yd = 1/2*amax*(t**2)  
        wd = amax*t    
        ad = amax
    elif t > T1:
        yd = amax*(t**6)  
        wd = amax*t    
        ad = amax
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

T1 = 3
T3 = 10

ydd = 0;
wdd = 0;
tt = 0;

## declare arrays to store the data
## size of arrays is bit tricky. 
## I am just calculating the number of times you are going to run the for loop. 
## The array has to be same size
t=0
i=0 

yd = np.zeros( int((T3-t)*1.0/0.001) )
wd = np.zeros( int((T3-t)*1.0/0.001) )
ad = np.zeros( int((T3-t)*1.0/0.001) )    
for t in np.arange (t,T3,0.001) :  
    if t <= T1:
        yd[i] = 1/2*amax*(t**2)  
        wd[i] = amax*t    
        ad[i] = amax
    elif t > T1:
        yd[i] = amax*(t**6)  
        wd[i] = amax*t    
        ad[i] = amax
    i = i+1
    ## store in the array instead of variable
```

you can now access all the values in yd, wd, and ad arrays 
Disclaimer: Posting without running the code as I am not sure what amax is.

Answer (score 0):

Do it without for loops. It's much faster (especially with *numpy!*) and more natural/readable for calculations which don't have interdependencies.

```
vals = np.arange(t, T3, 0.001)
cond = vals <= T1

yd = np.zeros_like(vals)
yd[cond] = (0.5 * amax * vals**2)[cond]
yd[!cond] = (amax * vals**6)[!cond]

wd = amax * vals
ad = np.full_like(vals, amax)
```

Comment: wow ~     
I think this is also a great solution !   Thank you!